# delay while opening view in wpf application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ms-access-2007

We are developing application using WPF,material design and MS-Access 2007 as Back End. Now we are facing problem of application slow down while opening single view ,that particular view have 16 combo's which fill. It take 7 seconds for process, following code used for bind combo box item source

```
     List<ComboBind> values = new List<ComboBind>();
     try
     {
      using (var oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand())
         {
             oleDbCommand.CommandText = query  ;
             oleDbCommand.Connection = Connection.con;
             var sql = query;
             var oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
         while (oleDbDataReader.Read())
             {
                 ComboBind b = new ComboBind();
                  b.id = oleDbDataReader[0].ToString().ToInt();
                  b.name = oleDbDataReader[1].ToString();
                  values.Add(b);                   
             }                
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

Comment: Step 1. Burn down `Access` it is a source of pure evil!
Step 2. Post xaml of your `ComboBox`.
I hope you are omitting `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: im using FilteredComboBox deriverd from combobox class    <wincontrol:FilteredComboBox                                                   IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False"                                                    Text="{Binding vmCustName}" ItemsSource="{Binding vmCustNameDataSource}" SelectedValuePath="id" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValue="{Binding vmCustSelectedValue}"              eventModule:SelectionChangedBehaviour.Command="{Binding CustSelectionChanged}"/>

Comment: There are 2 possibilities here: **1** your query to the database is taking a long time or **2** you have many records to display without `Virtualisation` enabled causing the app to create a lot of `U`I items. It is now down to you to find out which is your case. Could you also put that code in your Post.

Comment: VirtualizingStackPanel is true for combobox ItemsPanelTemplate also i use mode=recycling and when i run all query it display result quickly but when fire query from code it take time for result

Comment: If I understand you correctly when `ViewModel` is created it works quickly but when you trigger a `Command` it then takes time. In that case use [Skobarx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1785232/skobarx) answer. Because you need to use a background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load data in UI thread during view initialization and this is the reason of the issue. Either do loading of data in background thread or do it before opening the view.

Simple code snippet for loading data in separate task:

```
    //Might be your view code behind or
    //ViewModel if you are using MVVM
    public class ViewCodeBehind
    {
        public List<ComboBind> ComboItems { get; set; }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            //start bacground task for data loading
            var comboQuery = "select *from data";
            Task.Run(() => LoadItems(comboQuery));
        }

        public void LoadItems(string query)
        {
            List<ComboBind> values = new List<ComboBind>();
            try
            {
                using (var oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText = query;
                    oleDbCommand.Connection = Connection.con;
                    var sql = query;
                    var oleDbDataReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (oleDbDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        ComboBind b = new ComboBind();
                        b.id = oleDbDataReader[0].ToString().ToInt();
                        b.name = oleDbDataReader[1].ToString();
                        values.Add(b);
                    }
                }

                //use dispatcher to pass data back to UI thread
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ComboItems = values;
                    }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u @Skobarx for quick reply im new in WPF Just started MVVM so can u explain how could i avoid that

Comment: @SachinJadhav, what do you mean by "avoid that"? If you mean delays during data loading then the answer will be beyond this topic.

Comment: System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ComboItems = values;
                    }));  works great ... open view in 2 seconds thank you for help

Comment: You are welcome. To get more information about Distpatcher, you can google for 'wpf thred affinity'